# Kubernets (k3s): expired certs on cluster

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, k3s

I just lost access to my k3s.

I had the certs check this week to if if they had been auto-updated... and it seen so:

```
[root@vmpkube001 tls]# for crt in *.crt; do      printf '%s: %s\n'      "$(date --date="$(openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in "$crt"|cut -d= -f 2)" --iso-8601)"      "$crt"; done | sort
2021-09-18: client-admin.crt
2021-09-18: client-auth-proxy.crt
2021-09-18: client-cloud-controller.crt
2021-09-18: client-controller.crt
2021-09-18: client-k3s-controller.crt
2021-09-18: client-kube-apiserver.crt
2021-09-18: client-kube-proxy.crt
2021-09-18: client-scheduler.crt
2021-09-18: serving-kube-apiserver.crt
2029-11-03: client-ca.crt
2029-11-03: request-header-ca.crt
2029-11-03: server-ca.crt
```

but the cli is broken:
[image]

Same goes to the dashboard:

[image]

The cluster "age" was about 380~something days.
I am running a "v1.18.12+k3s1" in a centos7 cluster.

I change the date on the server to be able to execute kubectl again...
[image]
The secrets are wrong... how to update this?

Node logs:

```
Nov 18 16:34:17 pmpnode001.agrotis.local k3s[6089]: time="2020-11-18T16:34:17.400604478-03:00" level=error msg="server https://127.0.0.1:33684/cacerts is not trusted: Get https://127.0.0.1:33684/cacerts: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid"
```

Not only that but every case of this problem in the internet says somethings about kubeadm alpha certs. There is no kubeadm, and the only "alpha" feature i have in kubeclt is debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working.

it turn out that there is some bug in the auto-renew process. It has been patch up but they forgot to backport it to the 1.18 branch.
I Had to update it to 1.19.4 to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

To ignore this error, follow these steps:

**Step 1. Stop k3s**

```
systemctl stop k3s.service
```

**Step 2. Stop time sync**

```
hwclock --debug
    
timedatectl set-ntp 0
  
systemctl stop ntp.service 
    
systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service
```

**Step 3. Update date to <90 days from expiration**

```
date $(date "+%m%d%H%M%Y" --date="90 days ago")
```

**Step 4. Restart k3s**

```
systemctl start k3s.service
```

Just run this to test cluster!

```
kubectl get nodes
```